# Can I configure Google Cloud sql instance without billing?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to configure a Google Cloud SQL instance and I have to "Enable Billing".

Is there a way I can avoid enabling billing?

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud SQL currently does not offer any free trials, so you'll need to enable billing to use the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances by using gsutils command, bypass billing